# How to use a tf.keras model in a tf.data.Dataset generator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to use a pre-trained Keras model as part of my data processing to generate training data for a second Keras model. Ideally, I would like to do this by calling the first model in the data generator for the second model.

I am using tensorflow 1.15.

A simple example of what I'm trying to do is as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_core.python.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow_core.python.keras.layers import Dense

batch_size = 4
data_size = 16

model_generator = Sequential([Dense(data_size)])
model_generator.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
model_generator.build((batch_size, data_size))
sess = tf.keras.backend.get_session()

def generator():
    while True:
        data = np.random.random((batch_size, data_size))
        targets = tf.random.uniform((batch_size, 1))
        data = model_generator(data, training=False)
        data = data.eval(session=sess)
        yield (data, targets)

model_train = Sequential([Dense(data_size)])
model_train.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
model_train.build((batch_size, data_size))

output_types = (tf.float64, tf.float64)
output_shapes = (tf.TensorShape((batch_size, data_size)), tf.TensorShape((batch_size, 1)))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generator,
    output_types=output_types,
    output_shapes=output_shapes,
)

if next(generator()) is not None:
    print("Generator works outside of model.fit()!")

model_train.fit(
    dataset,
    epochs=2,
    steps_per_epoch=2
)
```

The snippet above produces the following error message when .fit() is called.:

```
2020-01-28 17:35:56.705549: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1639] Invalid argument: ValueError: Tensor("dense/kernel/Read/ReadVariableOp:0", shape=(16, 16), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("sequential/dense/Cast:0", shape=(4, 16), dtype=float32).
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

The code will run normally if the generator does not call the `model_generator` model. For example:

```py
def generator():
    while True:
        data = np.random.random((batch_size, data_size))
        targets = np.random.random((batch_size, 1))
        yield (data, targets)
```

I believe that the fit call creates its own tensorflow graph which does not include the nodes needed for `model_generator`. Is there any way to use one model in the generator used for training another model like this? If so, how can I modify the above example to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to have the graph connected between a `tf.Dataset` and a Keras model. Instead, what you need to do is find some way of creating a single model out of the two.

If the `model_generator` can be used directly as an input to your `model_train`, then the easiest way I can think of to do this is to create a Sequential model containing both models. Here's a simple example based on your snippet above. In this example, only `model_train` will be backpropogated through.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_core.python.keras import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow_core.python.keras.layers import Dense, Input

batch_size = 4
data_size = 16

def generator():
    while True:
        data = np.random.random((batch_size, data_size))
        targets = np.random.random((batch_size, 1))
        yield (data, targets)

model_generator = Sequential([Dense(data_size)])

# Freeze weights in your generator so they don't get updated
for layer in model_generator.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model_train = Sequential([Dense(data_size)])

# Create a model to train which calls both model_generator and model_train
model_fit = Sequential([model_generator, model_train])
model_fit.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
model_fit.build((batch_size, data_size))
model_fit.summary()

output_types = (tf.float64, tf.float64)
output_shapes = (tf.TensorShape((batch_size, data_size)),
                 tf.TensorShape((batch_size, 1)))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generator,
    output_types=output_types,
    output_shapes=output_shapes,
)

model_fit.fit(
    dataset,
    epochs=2,
    steps_per_epoch=2
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. It avoids the problem by moving the model out of the generator. If anyone has another solution where it can be left in, that would also be interesting to see. Although, I suspect that it may be very impractical to do so.